# Redirecting HTTP POST requests to HTTPS POST requests in asp.net Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, ssl, https

I recently setup my windows server to run over HTTPS with an SSL certificate.and I have a  problem to redirect HTTP request to https
I add this code in Global.asax

```
 protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {

        if (!Context.Request.IsSecureConnection))
            Response.Redirect(Context.Request.Url.ToString().Replace("http:", "https:"));
    }
```

but just GET request redirect and POST request failed.
please help me.

Comment: "POST request failed" isn't a good description of your problem. What indicates failure? When a POST request is responded with a redirect, the browser then issues a GET request to the redirected URL. It will not send the POST request to the new URL.

Comment: I get this message **The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.** of Postman and 500 Internal error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The best answer to this is to not redirect this as you desire**, rather it would be to redirect to a secure version of the referrer which will submit to an HTTPS URI.

1. Redirecting a POST request does not forward the data. Your request may have been redirected this way, and your code threw errors due to form values being NULL
2. The data that was submitted originally was not encrypted when it was originally posted.

Answer (score 0):

You should not ideally redirecting HTTP to HTTPS for POST request. Just don't allow POST request over HTTP. As you should aware POST request can't be use for bookmark or can't be cached.

So there is no meaning redirecting POST request to HTTPS.